# MAMP PRO + register globals

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

i've just started using MAMP pro, and whilst convertin all my Projects from ol' fashioned XAMPP to MAMP because of my switch from Win to Mac, i struggle with the php.ini-Options of MAMP Pro.

In special :

I have project which relies on register_globals. this is bad enough, i know, but nobody is going to pay for the kindness of removing this silly stuff.

But besides that, i can't get register_globals to work within MAMP, editing the php.ini with textwrangler and restarting the server does not have any effect. Also using File->Edit Templates does not do anything.

So, how can i get register_globals on with MAMP Pro. And yes, i tried .htaccess-ing ...

Thanks

Florian

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only suitable way i found was :

1. Remove MAMP
2. Install VirutalBox + Windows
3. Get Back to an classical LAMP ...

Comment: And continue running an obsolete version of PHP, which is very much vulnerable to a number of injection attacks on file IO functions?

Comment: LAMP means, Linux Apache Mysql Php/Perl, so no this is WAMP and not a LAMP stack :-)

Comment: I meant install Linux :D
But i'm not quite happy with that
On the other hand ... it's just for developing purpose when offline, so it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

I am using MAMP 3.0.6 and selected php 5.1.6 for a pretty much old project.

Opened the php.ini file at **/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.1.6/conf/php.ini**  and then did set **register_globals = On**

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't rely on register_globals, because **it is completely removed from PHP 5.4 and higher!**

If you really just need to make this project work, and get on with your life, you could make your own implementation:

```
function my_register_globals(){
    $gpcs = array($_GET,$_POST,$_COOKIE,$_SESSION);
    foreach((array)$gpcs as &$arr){
        foreach((array) $arr as $k => &$v){
            $GLOBALS[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
}
```

But my best recommendation is always to just scrap the project or rewrite if it uses register_globals!